# Treetop: How to make combined rule?

Tags: ruby, dsl, treetop

I want to make a simple JSP parser by using Treetop. Now, I have the following problem:

My basic grammar for starting is:

```
grammar Jspgrammar
    rule jspToken
        '<%'
    end

    rule jspPageToken
        jspToken '@page' 
    end
end
```

jspToken should match '<%' while jspPageToken should match '<%@page'

When I try this in irb:

```
   load 'jspgrammar.rb'
   parser=JspgrammarParser.new
   tree=parser.parse("<%")
   => SyntaxNode offset=0, "<%"
```

But when I try

```
   tree=parser.parse("<%@page")
   => nil
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:

[google groups on Treetop] : http://groups.google.com/group/treetop-dev/browse_thread/thread/3fecfa42a76e0034?pli=1